# Migrating from jboss 4.2 to jboss 6.0

Tags: migration

we are planned to migrate the server file which are working in jboss 4.2 to jboss 6.0,

---

application.xml

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd">

ModuleMenuEar

```
<ejb>ModuleMenuBean.jar</ejb>
```

```
<web>

  <web-uri>ModuleMenuWeb.war</web-uri>

 <context-root>/ModuleMenuWeb</context-root>

</web>
```

---

In jboss 4.2, if  is not available it takes  as context-root, but if we deploy the same file in jboss 6.0 its throwing error like required context-root, is the any xml confoguration which make jboss 6.0 work like jboss 4.0

---

IN ejb-jar.xml

```
    <session>

        <display-name>ModuleRightsSB</display-name>

        <ejb-name>ModuleRightsBean</ejb-name>

        <local-home>lrp.settings.modulerights.shared.ModuleRightsLocalHome</local-home>

        <local>lrp.settings.modulerights.shared.ModuleRightsLocal</local>

        <ejb-class>lrp.settings.modulerights.bean.ModuleRightsBean</ejb-class>

        <session-type>Stateless</session-type>

        <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>

        <resource-ref>

            <res-ref-name>jdbc/ReportDB</res-ref-name>

           <jndi-name>java:/REPORTDS</jndi-name>

            <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>

            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>

        </resource-ref>

          <resource-ref>

            <res-ref-name>jdbc/ClientDB</res-ref-name>

           <jndi-name>java:/MSSQLDS</jndi-name>

            <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>

            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>

        </resource-ref>

    </session>

</enterprise-beans>
```

---

in some ejb-jar.xml  file, we used   in ejb -jar.xml file itself , which is working properly in jboss 4.2, if we deploy the same file in jboss 6.0, its throwing error like required res-type, but its already available in ejb-jar.xml file,

Is there any xml configuration can be removed, so that it works without throeing any error,

kindly refer the attachment for more details

kindly help me to resolve this,

thanks in advance,

Vairam S

Comment: To help get more exposure add appropriate tags such as jboss, java etc

Answer (score 0):

`<jndi-name>java:/MSSQLDS</jndi-name>` is not a valid tag for `<resource-ref>`. Try removing that, then make sure the sub-tags are in the following order:

```
<res-ref-name>jdbc/ClientDB</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
```

If that doesn't work, providing your stack trace might be helpful.